# How to use a pattern for comparing similar String options?

Tags: java, string, while-loop, char

Trying to simplify this line of code

```
 }while(anw.equals("No") || anw.equals("n") || anw.equals("no"));
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: `anw.equalsIgnoreCase ("no") || anw.equals ("n")` **BUT** confused by your title - what has char [] got to do with it

Comment: There are plenty of ways. You can put all strings that you want to match in a sorted array, in a HashSet, or in a regex, for example. Searching on StackOverflow/Google should give you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (using `java.util.regex.Pattern`)? :

```
}while(Pattern.matches("[Nn]o?", anw));
```

The above code matches "N", "n", "No" and "no". If you need to match "NO" also, you can use:

```
}while(Pattern.matches("[Nn][Oo]?", anw));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Absolute noob here, much appreciated